# Update ActiveRecord attribute with SQL function

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In rails, are you able to update a record's attribute with an evaluation of a SQL function?

MySQL Table

```
| time_started        | time_to_execute |
|---------------------------------------|
| 2015-10-28 14:13:58 |      NULL       |
```

What I am trying to do:

```
update table set time_to_execute = TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), time_started))
```

through a model.

---

I've tried to do this using the common attribute update methods to no avail.

```
c.update_attribute(:time_to_execute, 'TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), time_started))')
c.update({:time_to_execute => 'TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), time_started))'})
```

#### Is it possible to update attributes of an ActiveRecord model using SQL functions?

I know that I can accomplish this executing arbitrary SQL, or calculating diff between two `DateTime` ruby objects, but I'm wondering if this is possible via a model method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `#update_all` to do this

```
c.class.where(id: c.id).update_all("time_to_execute = TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), time_started))")
```

Note that you can replace `c.class` with the actual class name of your model (not currently shown in the answer).

#### Update to show raw SQL implementation

```
c.class.connection.execute "update table set time_to_execute = TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), time_started)) WHERE id = #{ c.id }"
```

Comment: hey.. this looks promising.. but this wouldn't be going through the model, this would be going through an ActiveRecordAssociation.  I think it's probably "not possible" from a model itself?

Comment: You can execute raw SQL. I'll update my answer to show that.

Comment: no, definitely - i understand that.   is it possible to execute that on the model itself, FROM the model?  i'm thinking something like: `c.update_attribute_raw(:time_started, 'TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), time_started))')`  I just don't think this is possible - but i'd love to hear a definitive yes or no

Comment: sircapsalot do you mean the instance of the model?

Comment: yes @user3334690 .. sorry I didn't disambiguate that :)

Comment: @sircapsalot to my best knowledge what you are asking is not possible with ActiveRecord. I believe that it is possible with [ARel](https://github.com/rails/arel), however that would add quite a bit of complexity into the code.

Comment: We can't use this on creation of objects, can we?